# Pass DateTime value to a ASMX webMethod using Jquery Ajax

Tags: asp.net, datetime, jquery, asmx

Can some one help me to make a call to the web method who's signature is shown below.

```
public float[] GetTotalUagePerDay(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int[] type);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass a string to the webmethod and on the server run DateTime.Parse()

Comment: Thanks a lot..That's what I have been doing but I want to learn other means of doing the same..